# GmailClientAction in CardService

Tags: gmail-addons

I just noticed a **GmailClientAction** that is returned by  **CardService.newGmailClientAction()** and for which I cannot find any reference in the docs.

Does anybody for what and how to use this GmailClientActions?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 functions: setOpenChat, setReloadTask  in the client actions. Currently, there is no implementation given for those functionality.

Openchat action is to open chat for the current conversation.
ReloadTask is to reload the current mail view.

Comment: Hi Sabbu, that second one looks it's like the missing link for one of my addOns, do you have or know where I can find more info about it? First and foremost when will they be implemented? Cheers.

Comment: As of now, there is no plan for the implementation.

Comment: Hello again, I'm working on my scripts again, I wonder if there is something new about this? Cheers.